# JSP not finding a JDBC driver present in my WEB-INF/lib and in the build path

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Good Morning,

Here is my JSP code (note, it is just a slightly modified source from the Oracle Sample Application page here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97336_01/buslog.102/a83726/sampapp2.htm)

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

<HTML>
<HEAD> <TITLE> The JDBCQuery JSP  </TITLE> </HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR=white>

<% String searchCondition = request.getParameter("cond"); 
if (searchCondition != null) { %>
  <H3> Search results for : <I> <%= searchCondition %> </I> </H3>
  <%= runQuery(searchCondition) %>
  <HR><BR>
  <% }  %>

<B>Enter a search condition:</B>
<FORM METHOD=get> 
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="cond" SIZE=30>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Ask Oracle">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
<%! 
 private String runQuery(String cond) throws SQLException {
Connection conn = null; 
 Statement stmt = null; 
 ResultSet rset = null; 
 try {
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection((String)session.getAttribute  ("url"),
                                             "username", "pw");
          stmt = conn.createStatement();
          rset = stmt.executeQuery ("SELECT ename, sal FROM scott.emp "+ 
                                    (cond.equals("") ? "" : "WHERE " + cond ));
         return (formatResult(rset));
      } catch (SQLException e) { 
          return ("<P> SQL error: <PRE> " + e + " </PRE> </P>\n");
      } finally {
               if (rset!= null) rset.close(); 
               if (stmt!= null) stmt.close();
               if (conn!= null) conn.close();
      }
        }

   private String formatResult(ResultSet rset) throws SQLException {
     StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
     if (!rset.next())      
       sb.append("<P> No matching rows.<P>\n");
     else {  sb.append("<UL><B>"); 
          do {  sb.append("<LI>" + rset.getString(1) + 
                             " earns $ " + rset.getInt(2) + ".</LI>\n");
             } while (rset.next());
          sb.append("</B></UL>"); 
     }
     return sb.toString();
   }
 %>
```

The error occurs on lines:

```
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection((String)session.getAttribute("url"),
                                             "username", "pw");
```

where session throws an exception. Note that in the oracle code getValue is used instead of getAttribute, but get Value is depreciated. I've tried using a Class.forName() statement; however, this does not seem to solve the problem. Is there anything I have overlooked in this code? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Im using ojdbc14.jar package.

Edited to include error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 28 in the jsp file: /PGS/JDBCQuery.jsp
session cannot be resolved
 25:      ResultSet rset = null; 
 26:      try {
 27:         DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
 28:      conn = DriverManager.getConnection((String)session.getAttribute       ("url"),
 29:                                            "username", "pw");
 30:         stmt = conn.createStatement();
 31:         rset = stmt.executeQuery ("SELECT ename, sal FROM scott.emp"+
```

Comment: Can you paste the error you get. Stack trace

Comment: Business (and DB) logic in JSPs. OMG... That Oracle sample is dated  July 2000. You'll get more and more problems using this approach, that causes pain in the neck.

Comment: unintentional. Also, edited once again.

Comment: What is `session`? The error message simply says "*session cannot be resolved*" - It can not be complied because it doesn't exist.

Comment: why are you connecting to the DB from a JSP?  put this code in a java class that should be in the model part of your MVC implementatiin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the driver.

Al your data logic is inside a JSP declaration tag (<%! %>). The code inside that will be added to the servlet that will be generated from your code. In that context, the **session** variable doesn't exist.

What you are trying to accomplish would work if you changed the declaration (<%! %>) to a simple scriplet (<% %>) because in that context the **session** variable does exist and would work as you would expect.

But, as everyone told you already, you shouldn't be adding scriptlets to your jsp pages. Use a servlet with a RequestDispatcher to the jsp file and avoid adding any kind of java code into your jsp files.

Comment: I have very little experience, could you provide any reference in this context? Creating a class and calling it from a JSP.

Comment: JSP has several tags. <%! %> is used to include code in the servlet context and <% %> is used to include code in the page context.


If you need more info i'd say that you should read some JSP tutorials online, but for the problem that you are experiencing you should change your <%! into <% and that would make it work.

The problem is that "session" cannot be accesed from a JSP that way in a servlet context.


If you need to learn something about servlets / jsp let me recommend you the tutorials from coreservlets.com.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear, I meant reference material in the context of creating Java Classes and referring to them in jsp's. = coreservlets, thank you

Comment: Just change the <%! that's in your code (line 21) for a <% (without the exclamation mark "!") and your code should run properly. But you really need to learn some JSP/Servlet concepts.

Answer (score 4):

The problem has nothing to do with the driver. Your code doesn't compile, because you're defining a method which uses a variable `session` which doesn't exist. It's not a local variable nor an argument of your method, and it's not a field of your JSP either.

My advice: stop using scriptlets, and put this code in a Java class. JSPs are view components. they should only be used to generate markup, using the JSP EL, the JSTL and other custom tags. Data access code should be in separate classes, called from a controller implemented as a servlet.

Comment: I have very little experience, could you provide any reference in this context? Creating a class and calling it from a JSP.

Comment: Read the [JSP tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) and the [servlet tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)